# Op Amp as a simple switch

Tags: operational-amplifier, switches, dc, zener, dc-offset

I want to build a little voltage switch that switches on a buzzer and a relay when a certain voltage is reached. Please have a look at the schematic.

I use a trim potentiometer to set up the switch voltage so that it equals the zener voltage, in this case 3.3 volts. Then the Op Amp (741) switched to Vcc and drives the transistor (PN2222A) which switches on the 12V Relay and the buzzer. The Basis resistor is set in a way that I will have a Ic of around 150 mA.

So far so good.

My problem is that the Op Amp is not "ideal" and does not switch to 0V when the Voltage on the positive input is lower than the Zener voltage. There is about +2V, which is obviously enough to drive the transistor, so the relay/buzzer is always on.

There is also not a "hard switch" from 0 to Vcc, the Op Amp slowly increases the output voltage and then suddenly goes to Vcc.

I am aware of the DC offset problem, but how can I compensate it if I only have Vcc and 0V?

One other solution I found on the web was to put a feedback loop in. How do I dimension the feedback resistor?

These might be very basic questions, but I would appreciate your help.

Thanks in advance.

[image: schematics simple opamp switch]

Comment: You're using the op amp as a comparator. Any reason you aren't using a comparator? Also, you've used the symbol for a tunnel diode on what appears to be a zener diode. Also also, you should never use a 741. It's extremely obsolete.

Comment: Hi. Sorry, yes, the symbol is wrong. It is a Zener.  Quicky scribbled it. Re comparator: I assumed an OP amp is the simplest way to implement a comparator. Re 741. i might be outdated here. When i learned about this 30 years ago (and i forgot a lot) the 741 was up to date ;) what is a modern alternative?

Comment: A popular op amp for hobbyists is the LM358; two op amps in one package, cheap, and superior to the 741 in every way imaginable. But you want a comparator for this job, not an op amp. Try looking around [here](https://www.digikey.com/products/en/integrated-circuits-ics/linear-comparators/692) for a selection of comparators, and if you want to browse op amps, they have [those](https://www.digikey.com/products/en/integrated-circuits-ics/linear-amplifiers-instrumentation-op-amps-buffer-amps/687) too.

Comment: Thanks! So for instance a LM393 (first result) would be fine.

Comment: Note, however, that the LM393 has an open-drain output, not push-pull. It's capable of pulling the output down to ground (or close to it), but it requires an external pullup resistor if you want it to be able to pull high. You can get push-pull comparators; in fact, I believe digikey even has a searchable parameter for output type.

Comment: Thanks Felthry, that is very helpful . 
I found LT1017 for instance. Looks good, but will verify.

Comment: The reason the op amp is sluggish to go from off to on initially is that in the off state it's saturated--it's output is pulled as close to the negative rail as it can get, and it's still not at equilibrium because the inputs aren't equal.  Op-amps are generally slow to recover from saturation, which is one reason they make poor comparators.

Comment: If your relay actually takes 150 mA at 13 volts, then you need to set the base resistor so that the base current is about 10 - 15 mA. And if you go to a real comparator such as the LT1017, you need to be aware that it will not source any appreciable amount of current, so your circuit as shown simply won't work.

Comment: Thanks for all you responss. I will have a relay and a buzzer, so I will need 150 or 200 mA. With the LT1017 I can drive a transistor which provides the needed current. So the circuit as i drew up should work since the 1017 is push-pull. I also looked (and ordered) some LM393. Together with a NPN transistor i should be able to get a same result. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Hello again. I got the LT1017 now and set up the circuit. i run it from 14V, car voltage. I connected a LED with a resistor (500) to the output (pin 1), When the output of LT1017 is not connected / open, it goes to Vcc when the comparator switches on. When I connect the LED the voltage drops to abouth 1,7 V and the LED hardly lightens up. I assumed from the description of the LT1017 that it can actively drive up to 70mA and does not need a pull-up etc.? Could someone please advice? thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are using an op-amp as a comparator, not ideal but not the end of the world in many applications. Your circuit could work with the proper op-amp. You need one that can reach ground when its power supply is tied to ground. This is what most single-supply op-amps do, particularly if they have rail-to-rail outputs.

But if you are going to actually buy the parts (not just pick them up from a drawer) go for a real comparator.

Comment: Yes, i will buy the parts now. So will go for compartors. Thanks!