# Voltage alarm with LT1017

Tags: relay, comparator, pnp

With help of this site, I have redeveloped my voltage alarm circuit (see my [previous question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/405046/op-amp-as-a-simple-switch) for the history). I started off with an 741 Opamp and it did not work as I wanted it to work (Thanks for your input here). So I did some research and found a [LT1017 comparator](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/10178ff.pdf).

Based on the data sheet, I assumed that I can drive a LED with the output (it says in the datasheet that it can source 70 mA). But it does not work. The output voltage collapses under load.

Anyway, I switched it around and used a PNP transistor (2N2907) to drive a relay, LED and buzzer (See schematics).

So I still have issues and I don't understand why. The 2N2907 has a hfe of around 250 (measured with my multimeter). The buzzer, relay and LED use about 70 mA. Let's keep it simple and use a hfe of 100. This means I need 0.7mA as ib and with 14V Vcc we are at 14-0.7 at 13.3V/0.7mA, that would be 20k.

My problem: With this calculated Rb nothing happens. Even with Rb = 1k only the relay and LED works, the buzzer does not produce sound.

If I play with Rb and measure ib and ic, I get ib of around 10mA and a ic of 50mA. So the transistor has a hfe of 5 according to this.

I know that I must be making a massive error, but where is it? I learned that stuff 30 years ago and I am going back into it now a little. Of course I forgot many many things from back then, but what am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance for your input.

[image: schematic]

Comment: I made a new discovery. the transistor does not seem to be problem. The comparator does not switch between Vcc (14V) and 0 (which is my Vss) but stays on about 3.5V when the two input voltages are very close together. So this influences the transistor basis current and therefore the Ic. I thought that there will be a "clean switch" between Vcc and 0 when the one input becomes higher than the other. Is this not the point of a comparator? As always, looking forward to your thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

An hFE of only 5 implies you have swapped emitter and collector on the 2N2907. But at 14V, that would usually result in breakdown of E-B junction and can damage the transistor.

Comment: I double checked the polarity, so that should be fine. Is there anything wrong in your opinion with the schematics?